# Working with functions

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation

I am required to write a function that takes a function as a parameter.

```
moveTwoPoints[function_, {sliderMin_, sliderMax_}] := 
 DynamicModule[
  {sliderValue = sliderMin,
   plot},
  f[x_] := function;
  Column[
   {
(*Display slider *)
Slider[Dynamic[sliderValue], {sliderMin, sliderMax}],
(*Display updating slider value *)
Dynamic[sliderValue],
(*Display the graph with points moving*)
Dynamic[
 Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, sliderMin, sliderMax}], 
  Graphics[
   {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{sliderValue, f[sliderValue]}], 
    Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, f[sliderValue]}]
        }
       ]
      ]
     ]
    }
   ]
  ]
```

The problem I am running into is the fact that when I try f[sliderValue] is won't return a point just the value of function. Is there a way I can manipulate this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
f[func_, {Min_, Max_}] :=Manipulate[
  Column[{a,Plot[func[x], {x, Min, Max}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{a, func[a]}], 
      Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, func[a]}]}]}, 
  Alignment -> Center], {a, Min, Max}]
f[Sin[#] &, {0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant. The requirements for the problem are to create a slider and show a point along the y axis that mirrors a red point that follows the function. Your solution is great, I don't know if it would earn me full credit tho. How did you function change the values of the y coordinate using func[a]? I feel like my solution should have worked with that. @Chenminqi

Comment: Is there a way to do that without using manipulate? @chenminqi

Comment: Manipulate is a good function for dynamic demo.

Comment: Okay, manipulate makes sense but after re-reading the problem it states that I must use Dynamic Module. I will try to work with that. @chenminqi

Comment: Of course without using manipulate.But I need go to sleep ,so...tomorrow.

Comment: I think I answered the question I initially had. I was wondering how you could pass a defined function, f[x_] := Sin[x], as a parameter. Turns out all you have to pass is f.

Comment: `moveTwoPoints[func_, {Min_, Max_}] := DynamicModule[{x = Min}, {Slider[Dynamic[x],{Min,Max}],Dynamic[x],Plot[func[t], {t, Min, Max}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic@{x,func[x]}], Green, Point[Dynamic@{0, func[x]}]}]} // Column]
moveTwoPoints[Sin[#] &, {0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: I used a pure function as a parameter.